# How to find the value of a function after interpolation and differentiation of it in Maxima

Tags: function, interpolation, maxima, differentiation

There is such Maxima code

```
kill(all);load("interpol")$
q1:[[0,0.1], [0.25,0.2], [0.5,0.3], [0.75,0.4]];
f1(x):=''(cspline(q1));
qt1(x):=''(diff(f1(x),x,1));
```

I want to find the value of the obtained function `qt1(x)` for `x=1`. Then I write `qt1(0.3);` and I get massage

```
diff: variable must not be a number; found: 0.3
#0: qt1(x=0.3) (interpol.mac line 106)
-- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

What should be done?

Comment: I see that after qt1(x):=''(diff(f1(x),x,1)); the terms remain with dx.They were not calculated. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxima does not know how to differentate `charfun2`. You can teach it.

```
load("interpol") $

q: [[0,0.1], [0.25,0.2], [0.5,-0.3], [0.75,1.4]] $

gradef(charfun2(x, A, B), 0) $

e:  cspline(q)  $
de: diff(e, 'x) $

define( f('x),  e) $
define(df('x), de) $

draw2d(explicit(f('x), 'x, 0, 1), 'color='red, explicit(df('x), 'x, 0, 1)) $
```

I changed points in `q'.